# Why is my Facebook [recommend] button getting cut off at bottom?

Tags: facebook

Why is my button being cut off at the bottom?  It should have a height of 21px.  It's visible here:

http://mayacove.com/dev/sm/test_like.html

Answer (score 2):

You could try hand-code a css file with something like the following

```
a.connect_widget_like_button {
    padding:3px 4px !important;
}
```

Although admittedly this is sort of a kludge.

EDIT: The other answer seems better, but you also seem to need a bigger width. You should modify your inline iframe styles.

```
<iframe [...] height:23px; width:101px; [...]>
```

Comment: He's actually got two widths in there: width:450px; height:24px; width:100px;

Comment: @Dan Good catch, although it seems only the last one is being applied. I modified the 100px I saw in the chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ the height of the iframe should be 35px when using the standard layout. If you look at the dimensions of your button, it's got a height of 24px, so it just isn't going to fit into 21px.

Answer (score 1):

The height of your iFrame is not tall enough to fit the entire button. Plus you have assigned an inline style of `overflow:hidden` so any excess content will not show.

If you change the iFrame height from 21px to something like 24px, it shows up the full button:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?&lt;%=thisURL%&gt;&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=recommend&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:24px; width:100px; overflow:hidden; " allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Also, I noticed in your iFrame inline style you have assigned two widths:

... `width:450px; height:24px; width:100px`; ...

You will need to remove one of those declarations.

Regards,
Dan